# Relative Imports and Unit Testing

Tags: python, testing, import, directory

I've been working on a project where I have a directory system that looks like this:

```
tests/
    corpus/
        tests.py
monkey/
    corpus/
        corpus.py

setup.py
```

I have `__init__.py`'s strewn throughout these directories, also.

The issue is that when I attempt to run `corpus/tests.py`, it complains about a line of code like this: `import monkey.corpus as corpus`.

It (understandably) works when run with a `-m` switch from the root dir or have a tests.py file in the root directory. Which of these two (or possibly other options) is the most preferable if I want to automate multiple tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put an `__init__` file in the level of `tests` and `monkey`, and include it to the `sys.path`. It's clearly more practical, since you don't have to specify the parameter each time you call it.

Also, if someone else is going to use your code, obviouly they wouldn't expect to specify `-m` argument every time they run the file :)

So, in the `__init__` file of the root directory:

```
root/
   /tests
   /monkey
   __init__.py
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `setuptools`, you can specify the test suite in your setup.py and run the tests using `python setup.py test`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    test_suite='tests'
    ...)
```

Another way is to run `nosetests` from the `nose` package from the root of your directory.

**Note** The test files may not be executable for both methods I mentioned.